# Adding negative numbers in List Python

Tags: python

What is wrong with following python code.

```
List3=[7,5,4,4,3,1,-2,-3,-5,-7]
total=0
i=6
while i>=6:
    total = total + List3[i]
    i=i+1
    if i> len(List3):
        break
print(total)
```

Shouldn't the while loop start adding at List3[6]=-2 and break when i is greater than the length of the list. What is wrong with my logic? 
It returns:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-7e2f7eca2eb8> in <module>()
  4 i=6
  5 while 6<= i:
----> 6     totaln = totaln + List3[i]
  7     i=i+1
  8     if i> len(List3):

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: I assume that you want `i=i+1` moved one tab to the right. Otherwise the while loop will never terminate.

Comment: The indentations are wrong, so the `return` is outside the `while` loop and is causing an error. This has nothing to do with negative numbers.

Comment: GalAbra Sorry I corrected my post. The indentation were this updated version.

Comment: The error talks of `totaln`, you code uses `total`. This is still not the real code. And `List3` can not look like you show it here.

Comment: I've downvoted your question because the code you show us is not the code that produces the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrong order of the statements, you should check if you're not accessing elements beyond the end of the list first, and only then actually access them:

```
while i>=6:
    if i>= len(List3):  # this moved here, also note `>=` instead of `>`
        break

    total = total + List3[i]
    i += 1
```

Finally, all your code can be written as a simple single line of the code:

```
sum( List3[6:] )  # that's it!!
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. Since you seem like a exprerienced user of the site, can you give me any pointers on posting on this site? I'm new and I don't understand why I got two downvotes. Onve again thanks.

Comment: @BarinderSingh don't worry about that. all people make mistakes sometimes. in your case, people wrote in the comments what they find strange in your question. like bad code formatting, that makes it hard to understand, or wrong variable names between the code and the output it generates, that makes it harder to understand. there are guidelines on "How to Ask Questions", hopefully this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

I think the `while` loop  is error. the `i = i+1` and if condition should be in the `while` loop. The second point is the `i >= len(List3)` is enough. The `i > len(List3)` will result the last index out of index range

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code was in the last iteration line no 7 will become  10 >10 which will false and hence it doesn't break out of the loop. And it will try to access List[10] at line no 5, which is not there, so it will break with the error `IndexError: list index out of range` as List3 has length of 10 which means last element is at index 9.

Modified version of your code that will work

```
  List3=[7,5,4,4,3,1,-2,-3,-5,-7]
  total=0
  i=6
  while i>=6:
    total = total + List3[i]
    i=i+1
    if i > len(List3) - 1:
      break
  print(total)
```

But the right way if you want to get Sum of all negative numbers in any list

```
total=0
for i in List3:
    if i<0:
    total += i
print(total)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the last iteration the internal if computes 10>10 which returns false, hence it doesn't break out of the loop. And it continues to get List[10] - which is invalid, hence it breaks the code.

Replace `if i> len(List3):` with `if i>= len(List3):`. It should work

Comment: Thank you.That worked. How can I better post questions so Idon't get downvotes? I'm new to the site. Once again thanks.

Comment: I think you got down votes probably because it was a very basic question and you could've solved it by yourself if you had given some more time thinking about each iteration and what it does. I think it shows lack of efforts and eagerness to seek solution from others - might not be always true. This is what I think. Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
total=0
for i in list3:
    if i<0:
        total+=i
```